# website hosted in AWS does not show up

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting

i've registered a .com domain name. At the Amazon Web Services account i own, I have already set up the DNS zone,i've changed the nameservers at my registrar's panel and i've created an A-record in my AWS DNS zone,too. I think i've done all the preparation needed. But my website is not opening!

This is not a DNS propagation time-requiring issue,by the time i did all the above stuff about 5 days ago (DNS had enough time to be refreshed globally in any ISP). Also via ipduh.com i can see that all the nameservers are correctly configured and recognised, as well as the *.mydomain.com A record which points at my AWS instance's IP.

What possibly would be wrong guys? :/ i've done anything i know and i've followed also the directions i've found in SO and i had no luck till now :/

Any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated :D

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the DNS is set up properly, and that the A record is pointing at the IP address assigned to your instance.

If this is a new AWS account, you're probably running in a VPC.  Did you make sure that you allocated a public IP address to the instance?  If your IP is 10.something, that's the internal, private IP address and you won't be able to use that.  You'll need to allocate an Elastic IP and associate it with your instance, then update your DNS settings.

Next, make sure that the web server is up & running?  If you log into the instance, what happens if you `wget localhost`?  You might not get the page you're expecting if you're running multiple name-based virtualhosts, but you should get the index page for the default web site.

OK, so how you're sure the web server is running.  Next thing to do is check the security rules.  When you created your instance, you had give it the name of a security group.  The default is, strangely enough, called "defaut".  Take a look and see if port 80 is open.  If not, open it up to the world (0.0.0.0) and see if you can access the web site now.

None of this helps?  Reboot your instance and see if it starts working when it comes back up - it's possible that you're on a bad host, and rebooting will bring it up on different hardware.

Comment: yes,of course i've configured correctly the DNS,the IPs and everything with the instance. After wget localhost,it returned me back the custom index html page i had created. Apache service is running,but actually port 80 seems to be closed,even though i tried to open it via iptables..i rebooted,several times,but the problem persists :/

Comment: finally fixed it! I created a new security group and added my instance there,after allowing this group to see the world (0.0.0.0) and i rebooted. Now everything is ok,thank you :D

Comment: If you modify your security groups, you don't need to reboot - changes generally take effect almost immediately.